# PostgreSQL: Convert MongoDB date format to timestamptz

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have referred to the psql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) and came up with this query.

`SELECT to_timestamp('Tue Aug 30 2016 04:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)', 'Dy MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS');`

This date time string `Tue Aug 30 2016 04:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)` is what I got from MongoDB printjson(createdAt).

The above postresql doesn't seem to work correctly for all offsets.

I tried this

```
select to_timestamp('Tue Aug 30 2016 04:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)', 'Dy MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS "GMT"OF "(IST)"');
```

But I get this error ``ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date`.

How to convert to psql timestamptz format from this string `Tue Aug 30 2016 04:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks an ugly wheel and requires such `replace` for each unrecognized offset, but it works. For your sample replace `'GMT+0530 (IST)'` to `'GMT+05:30'` and it will be picked up:

```
t=# select replace('Tue Aug 30 2016 04:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+05:30')::timestamptz;
        replace
------------------------
 2016-08-30 09:37:13+00
(1 row)
t=# select replace('Tue Aug 30 2016 14:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+05:30')::timestamptz;
        replace
------------------------
 2016-08-30 19:37:13+00
(1 row)
```

**update**: depending on your timezone result can be confusing:

```
t=# set timezone TO 'GMT-5:30';                                          SET
t=# select replace('Tue Aug 30 2016 14:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+05:30')::timestamptz;
          replace
---------------------------
 2016-08-31 01:07:13+05:30
(1 row)
```

to check if it is right, use:

```
t=# select replace('Tue Aug 30 2016 14:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+05:30')::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC';
      timezone
---------------------
 2016-08-30 19:37:13
(1 row)
```

Comment: Does it take care of 24 hours format ? I think the query is converting my 24 hours clock to 12 hours !!

Comment: Thanks Vao. When I tried, it wasn't converting properly. Does it have anything to do with the system clock settings as well ? I will check with few examples to convince myself.

Comment: post samples?.. It's hard to tell before you see the exact error

Comment: `select replace('Tue Aug 30 2016 14:07:13 GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+0530 (IST)','GMT+05:30')::timestamptz;` gives `2016-08-31 01:07:13+05:30`. I am in +0530 zone. Is this correct ?

Comment: updated the answer with way to check. also yo ucan set timezone for your client to avoid double conversion mess

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. I will have to store in timestamp without time zone format. If you can, plz try to look at this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780737/log-specific-postgresql-query-using-pg-promise

Comment: ask @vitaly-t - he's quite active on SO