# Log specific postgresql query using pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) package with Nodejs to execute PostgreSQL queries. I want to see the queries executed. Only specific queries, say, just one query that I want to debug.

I can see that one recommended way is to use the [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) to catch the events and log them as mentioned here in the examples [documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#simple-select).

Without using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), is there a simple way to just print the prepared query that is executed. I can't see it in the docs.

Example:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $/id/", {id: 2})
```

How to print this query to yield?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> is there a simple way to just print the prepared query that is executed...

A query in general - yes, see below. A [Prepared Query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html) - no, those are by definition formatted on the server-side.

```js
const query = pgp.as.format('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $/id/', {id: 2});
console.log(query);
await db.any(query);
```

And if you want to print all queries executed by your module, without using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), simply add event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) handler when initializing the library:

```js
const initOptions = {
  query(e) {
    console.log(e.query);
  }
};
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);
```

Comment: The `options` is awesome. I am yet to explore it fully. Thanks.

Comment: not sure this question might be related to options - for quicker visibility commenting here. Pl check. Thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152018/pg-promise-timeout-while-using-express-generator-format-but-works-fine-with-bas

Comment: when I see a library with too many open issues I often go and tell them "maybe you should manage a library like vitaly-t" first