# Pg Promise timeout while using express generator format, but works fine with basic express sever

Tags: node.js, express, pg, pg-promise, express-generator

Pg-promise is Not returning anything for 60s and gets timed out while running server setup with express-generator.
There are no error messages.

All the routes without `db.any` or similar query, works fine. The routes with `db.*` times out.

But, the same connection/route/query works perfectly with a simple express app.

I am running this from AWS EC2.

Here is the test sample express that worked fine.
Same route in routes/index.js does not work - gets timed out.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const options = {
  query: function (e) {
    console.log(e.query);
  },
};

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
const connection = 'postgres://user:pwd@endpoint:5432/db';
const db = pgp(connection);

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  db.any('select id from users')
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        data,
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      res.json({
        err,
      });
    });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('db app listening on port 4000!');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Not sure what I am missing? What could be the issue!

Comment: More info: The problem seems to occur when pg connection is created in another file and being imported to routes!! Not exactly an express-generator issue. But still unresolved.

Comment: It's all AWS-related issues, of which there have been numerous discussions against the [underlying driver](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).

Comment: I see. Thanks for replying. The same setup is working fine on local as well as other AWS instances is what I observed too.